# How to use SQL Cross Join instead of UNPIVOT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot, cross-join

I need to use following query in HANA. But Unpivot function is not available in HANA. If I can use cross join here instead of Unpivot, it is easy to convert to HANA SQL. How to do it?

```
SELECT p.CardName, REPLACE(p.groupcode1,'QryGroup','') groupcode1, ocqg.GroupName
FROM ocrd UNPIVOT 
( value
 FOR groupcode1 IN ([QryGroup1],[QryGroup2],[QryGroup3],
[QryGroup4],[QryGroup5],[QryGroup6],[QryGroup7],[QryGroup8],
[QryGroup9],[QryGroup10],[QryGroup11],[QryGroup12],[QryGroup13],
[QryGroup14],[QryGroup15],[QryGroup16],[QryGroup17],[QryGroup18],
[QryGroup19],[QryGroup20],[QryGroup21],[QryGroup22],[QryGroup23],
[QryGroup24],[QryGroup25],[QryGroup26],[QryGroup27],[QryGroup28],
[QryGroup29],[QryGroup30],[QryGroup31],[QryGroup32],[QryGroup33],
[QryGroup34],[QryGroup35],[QryGroup36],[QryGroup37],[QryGroup38],
[QryGroup39],[QryGroup40],[QryGroup41],[QryGroup42],[QryGroup43],
[QryGroup44],[QryGroup45],[QryGroup46],[QryGroup47],[QryGroup48],
[QryGroup49],[QryGroup50],[QryGroup51],[QryGroup52],[QryGroup53],
[QryGroup54],[QryGroup55],[QryGroup56],[QryGroup57],[QryGroup58],
[QryGroup59],[QryGroup60],[QryGroup61],[QryGroup62],[QryGroup63],
[QryGroup64])
         ) as p,
         ocqg
    WHERE value = 'Y' and 
    ocqg.GroupCode = REPLACE(p.groupcode1,'QryGroup','')
    order by groupcode1
```

Table structure as follows

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a "cross tab"?

Comment: @Larnu No.Sql Cross Join. To convert Columns into rows

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` doesn't "convert" columns into rows; it create a Cartesian product between 2 objects..

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say `CROSS APPLY`?

Comment: @kith . . . This was exactly answered on your previous question.